# SQL selecting rows with matching values

Tags: php, sql, select

i'm trying to put together a SELECT statement using php and sql, but i'm having a hard time trying to select the items I want.

lets say my table looks like this...

---

```
master_record_id     credit_id     credit_value
118                  5             Brian J
119                  5             Brian J
120                  7             Katie W
121                  5             Brian J
121                  7             Katie W
125                  7             Katie W
```

---

I'm trying to find which `master_record_id` has both Katie W and Brian J in it. So I selected for `credit_value = Brian J OR Katie W` and this is the result.

Based on this small selection, I can see that the answer I want is `121` but how can I select for that? I want to find the `master_record_id` that contains both Katie W and Brian J...

Is there a way for me to say, "SELECT the master_record_id  that contains both Katie W and Brian J"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a *self-join*:

```
SELECT a.master_record_id
FROM tablename a JOIN tablename b USING (master_record_id)
WHERE a.credit_value = 'Brian J'
AND b.credit_value = 'Katie W'
```

Comment: this seems to be working perfectly. let me work it into my code and see how it performs.

Answer (score 1):

```
select master_record_id
from your_table
where credit_value in ('Brian J', 'Katie W')
group by master_record_id
having count(distinct credit_value) = 2
```

YOou have to adjust the value in the `having` clause to the number of values in your `in` clause.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way to do that because of the performance, but anyway it should work:

```
select master_record_id, credit_id, credit_value
from your_table
where master_record_id in (
     select master_record_id from your_table where credit_value = 'Brian J')
and master_record_id in (
         select master_record_id from your_table where credit_value = 'Katie W')
```

It will return all the **master_record_id** records which has both Katie W and Brian J in it